# Is it necessary to place php file for uploading pdf file using restful webservices

Tags: android, file-upload, restful-architecture

My question is i am using restful web services URL to upload PDF file in server
but i did not file any specific way to upload them if any has solution for that
or is it necessary to place php file for uploading file thought restful url

Comment: It's up to you how you want to structure the WebService, you can do it with PHP, Python, .NET or whatever you want

Comment: i want to do it with just url not with php script if you have any code or suggestion for that please give us

Comment: How can you do it without any coding? Somewhere you will have to put the logic

Comment: ok understood so its necessary to place php file in tomcat Apache server